# Python calculating square root of 2

Tags: python, square

Im doing a simple python task calculating square root of 2 of the input number.
Ex. input number = 3 -> 2x2x2
But my code is not working and I can't find the reason why.
Can anyone correct them or tell me whats wrong??

```
def poweroftwo(N):
    result = 0
    for n in range(1,N + 1):
        result = result + 2**2
    return result




    
def main():
    num=int(input("Give a number: "))
    var1 = poweroftwo(num)
    print("The result is",var1)



    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's not a square root.  The square root of 2 is the number which, when squared, is two.  You are trying to calculate a power of two, i.e. 2\*\*n.  There is a builtin Python operator to do that.  But repeatedly adding 2\*\*2, which is just 4, isn't what you want.

Comment: You mean you want to an operation of 2^n (2 to the n-th power)?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr No, OP want's 2\*\*n.  The ^ operator in Python is bitwise exclusive OR, which OP does not want.

Comment: @TomKarzes I didn't mean for the ^ to be interpreted as a python operator. It's how I usually write power in math terminology. [Reference](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/caret.htm#:~:text=Alternatively%20referred%20to%20as%20the,or%206%20*%206%20*%206.)

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I know, but in this instance using non-Python notation merely confuses an already confused issue.

Comment: @TomKarzes Hence, I clarified the meaning of the symbol by explaining what it does in the parentheses.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Or, you could just use \*\* and not have to explain that you're using it in a different sense than how Python uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Three different things are mixed up:

1. the square-root of 2: `2**.5`,
2. the `N`-th power of 2: `2**N`,
3. `N * 4` in function `poweroftwo` (as commented by *Tom Karzes*, the function `poweroftwo` compute `N * 2**2` instead of `2**N`).

I assume the actual goal is #2, so a correct code is:

```py
def main():
    num = int(input("Give a number: "))
    print("The result is", 2**num)

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are continuously adding four (`2**2`), this is not a viable solution for working out `2n` (which is what you appear to be doing despite the mention of square roots in the title).

The following code will do the desired task for non-negative integers, assuming you don't want to just use the in-built Python `**` power operator (even though your current code *is* using it for adding four):

```
def poweroftwo(n):
    if type(n) != int: return None
    if n < 0: return None
    result = 1
    while n > 0:
        result *= 2
        n -= 1
    return result

for x in range(9):
    print(x, poweroftwo(x))
```

The output of that is:

```
0 1
1 2
2 4
3 8
4 16
5 32
6 64
7 128
8 256
```

Comment: For non-negative integer exponentiation, you really only need O(log(n)) multiplications rather than O(n).  I realize that this is a clear, simple way to do it, but it's worth noting that it's not efficient.